# Random JSON error in my Shopify section?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, shopify, liquid

I need to add sections to a page. Hear me out. I know that this topic has been beat to death, but I feel like I have the answer, I just don't know entirely how to understand it.

> I have been working hard to understand and implement the following tutorial in my client's store...... https://oak.works/blog/technical/2017/03/23/shopify-sections-editor/

I am brand new to Stack Overflow, not brand new to Shopify or the theme code, but I'm very green. So PLEASE take it easy on me... So far, after much painful research, I've determined (guessed) that the following steps are the most likely route that will lead to success:

> 1. making a new alternate page template, mine: `page.portfolio.liquid`
> 2. creating a snippet of the original section's code, just the top part (sans schema), mine: `snippet-collection-callout.liquid`
> 3. creating a new section, using the code (from the article) to render blocks into the section and calling the snippet for settings as shown in the tutorial I think? (BELOW, called `section-portfolio-page.liquid`)
> 4. defining the schema (copy and paste) from the original section `collection-callout.liquid`to the new section (BELOW, called `section-portfolio-page.liquid`)
> 5. calling the section into the new page template `page.portfolio.liquid` with `{% section 'section-portfolio-page' %}`
> 6. creating a new page in Shopify admin, "Portfolio Page"
> 7. assigning the new alternate page template to `page.portfolio`and ensuring navigation is there
> 8. navigate to the new page through theme editor, which should show a static section that I can enter and customize via blocks.

But I'm stuck on step 4, because it is kicking back this error:

> `Error: Invalid JSON in tag 'schema'`

I KNOW that sections on pages is possible. But I want to cry. Could anybody just take a look at the article, my steps, and the code below and nudge me in the right direction? Let me know after reading this if one of my steps is wrong somehow, or even just explain where the JSON error is?

I'm about 173 hours into trying to figure this out and my kids aren't amused. Not joking. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

> Here is the original section I am trying to recreate and piece together, for use on a page:

```
{%- assign collection = collections[section.settings.collection] -%}
{%- assign isEmpty = false -%}

{% if section.settings.collection == blank %}
  {%- assign isEmpty = true -%}
{% endif %}

{% if section.settings.divider %}<div class="section--divider">{% endif %}

<div class="page-width">
  <div class="feature-row feature-row--small-none">

    <div class="feature-row__item feature-row__callout-image">
      <div class="callout-images {% if isEmpty %}blank-state{% endif %}" data-aos="collection-callout">
        {% if isEmpty %}
          {% for i in (1..5) %}
            {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
            <div class="callout-image">{{ 'product-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
          {% for product in collection.products limit: 5 %}
            <img src="{{ product | img_url: '300x' }}" alt="{{ product.title }}" class="callout-image">
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="feature-row__item feature-row__text feature-row__text--{{ section.settings.layout }} feature-row__callout-text larger-text">
      {% if section.settings.subtitle %}
        <p class="subtitle">{{ section.settings.subtitle }}</p>
      {% endif %}
      {% if section.settings.title != blank %}
        <h2 class="h3">{{ section.settings.title }}</h3>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="rte">
        {% if section.settings.text != blank %}
          <p>{{ section.settings.text }}</p>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      {% if section.settings.cta_text1 != blank %}
        <a href="{{ section.settings.cta_link1 }}" class="btn">
          {{ section.settings.cta_text1 }}
        </a>
      {% endif %}
      {% if section.settings.cta_text2 != blank %}
        <a href="{{ section.settings.cta_link2 }}" class="btn">
          {{ section.settings.cta_text2 }}
        </a>
      {% endif %}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

{% if section.settings.divider %}</div>{% endif %}


{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Collection callout",
    "class": "index-section",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "collection",
        "id": "collection",
        "label": "Collection"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "subtitle",
        "label": "Subtitle",
        "default": "Brand new"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "title",
        "label": "Title",
        "default": "Collection callout"
      },
      {
        "type": "textarea",
        "id": "text",
        "label": "Text",
        "default": "Use this section to easily call attention to one of your collections. We'll show photos of the first 5 products."
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "cta_text1",
        "label": "Button #1 text",
        "default": "Shop Jackets"
      },
      {
        "type": "url",
        "id": "cta_link1",
        "label": "Button #1 link"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "cta_text2",
        "label": "Button #2 text",
        "default": "Shop All Mens"
      },
      {
        "type": "url",
        "id": "cta_link2",
        "label": "Button #2 link"
      },
      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "layout",
        "label": "Layout",
        "default": "right",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "left",
            "label": "Text on left"
          },
          {
            "value": "right",
            "label": "Text on right"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "divider",
        "label": "Show section divider",
        "default": false
      }
    ],
    "presets": [{
      "name": "Collection callout",
      "category": "Collection"
    }]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

> Here is the code for the new `section-portfolio-page.liquid` I am trying to save, but getting an error for:

```
<div>
 {% for block in section.blocks %}
 <div class="grid-item" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
   {% case block.type %}

     {% when 'callout' %}
     {% include 'snippet-collection-callout' %}

   {% endcase %}
 </div>
 {% endfor %}
</div>

{% schema %}
  {
    "blocks": [
      {
    "name": "Collection callout",
    "class": "index-section",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "collection",
        "id": "collection",
        "label": "Collection"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "subtitle",
        "label": "Subtitle",
        "default": "Brand new"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "title",
        "label": "Title",
        "default": "Collection callout"
      },
      {
        "type": "textarea",
        "id": "text",
        "label": "Text",
        "default": "Use this section to easily call attention to one of your collections. We'll show photos of the first 5 products."
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "cta_text1",
        "label": "Button #1 text",
        "default": "Shop Jackets"
      },
      {
        "type": "url",
        "id": "cta_link1",
        "label": "Button #1 link"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "cta_text2",
        "label": "Button #2 text",
        "default": "Shop All Mens"
      },
      {
        "type": "url",
        "id": "cta_link2",
        "label": "Button #2 link"
      },
      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "layout",
        "label": "Layout",
        "default": "right",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "left",
            "label": "Text on left"
          },
          {
            "value": "right",
            "label": "Text on right"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "divider",
        "label": "Show section divider",
        "default": false
      }
    ],
    "presets": [{
      "name": "Collection callout",
      "category": "Collection"
    }]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing 2 brackets.

Here is the correct JSON schema:

```
{
   "blocks":[
      {
         "name":"Collection callout",
         "type":"collection",
         "settings":[
            {
               "type":"collection",
               "id":"collection",
               "label":"Collection"
            },
            {
               "type":"text",
               "id":"subtitle",
               "label":"Subtitle",
               "default":"Brand new"
            },
            {
               "type":"text",
               "id":"title",
               "label":"Title",
               "default":"Collection callout"
            },
            {
               "type":"textarea",
               "id":"text",
               "label":"Text",
               "default":"Use this section to easily call attention to one of your collections. We'll show photos of the first 5 products."
            },
            {
               "type":"text",
               "id":"cta_text1",
               "label":"Button #1 text",
               "default":"Shop Jackets"
            },
            {
               "type":"url",
               "id":"cta_link1",
               "label":"Button #1 link"
            },
            {
               "type":"text",
               "id":"cta_text2",
               "label":"Button #2 text",
               "default":"Shop All Mens"
            },
            {
               "type":"url",
               "id":"cta_link2",
               "label":"Button #2 link"
            },
            {
               "type":"select",
               "id":"layout",
               "label":"Layout",
               "default":"right",
               "options":[
                  {
                     "value":"left",
                     "label":"Text on left"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"right",
                     "label":"Text on right"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "type":"checkbox",
               "id":"divider",
               "label":"Show section divider",
               "default":false
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "presets":[
      {
         "name":"Collection callout",
         "category":"Collection"
      }
   ]
}
```

In addition I added a type `collection` to the block, since there was no type.

Comment: Thank you!! I will try this asap. Out of curiosity, would you be able to tell me if you think I'm on the right track here in my steps I'm planning on taking?

Comment: @kiefly There is no "right" track in development especially for Shopify. You code it in a such what that it meets your needs, every developer has his ways. At the moment you have a bare bone `for` loop with a `case` inside it, i.e. not too much code to work with. You are checking the `block.type` but you didn't have a block type ( you will have to call your block `callout` instead of the `collection` one I entered in order for your code to work ). So to sum it up, learn the basic syntax and logic for Liquid and worry later for "right" ways.

Comment: Thank you so much for your constructive feedback here! I really appreciate it. That gives me a place to start researching. I suppose I just wonder if the steps I have outlined here seem like they accurately match the steps this tutorial is explaining/if I am understanding the instructions properly? It wasn't very clear to me in some parts. To clarify, you added `collection` at the very top, labeling it as "type" instead of "class," and I will need to change this to `callout` instead, right?

Comment: @kiefly pretty much yes. Blocks can't have a `class` attribute, but they must have a `name` and `type` ( and `settings` ).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much @drip I will work on these things and see how it turns out.

Comment: your suggestions worked almost flawlessly! I am seeing the section, with dynamic block options, available in the theme editor for the page now. The only issue is it doesn't actually let me make any changes to the text, section placement, buttons, etc. (the fields show up to make those edits, but placeholder values and any changes that I make to those settings don't actually reflect on the page at all). Would you first look to the snippet file, the case statement, or the schema for that? I'm deep diving this matter presently, but figured I would ask in case you had any insight.